# Yii 1 Middleware de auditoría

Tags: php, yii

actualmente en el sistema de la compañía donde trabajo se requiere implementar auditorías de cada acción que realice un usuario en el mismo.

Ya toda la lógica que realiza esta tarea, se encuentra desarrollada en un componente independiente, sin embargo, necesito llamar ese componente en algún lado por donde pasen absolutamente todas las peticiones HTTP sin importar el verbo utilizado y no se en que parte o como hacerlo. Esta es mi primer interacción con Yii 1.

```
AuditoriaConsultaComponent::auditarConsulta();
```

Esa es la línea que invoca el componente y no se en que sitio implementarla, o que archivo crear para lograr mi objetivo.

Quedo muy atento a su colaboración.

Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Logré lo que necesitaba y la respuesta que me ayudó fue [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27180098/8350297) y básicamente dice lo siguiente:

> En caso de que necesite ejecutar un código antes de cada controlador y
>   acción, puede hacer lo siguiente:
>
> **1** - Agregue un componente a su directorio de componentes, por ejemplo (MyGlobalClass):
>
> ```
> namespace app\components;
> class MyGlobalClass extends \yii\base\Component{
>     public function init() {
>         echo "Hi";
>         parent::init();
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> **2** - Agregue el componente MyGlobalClass a su matriz de componentes en el archivo de configuración:
>
> ```
> 'components' => [
>     'MyGlobalClass'=>[
>         'class'=>'app\components\MyGlobalClass'
>      ],
>      //other components
> ```
>
> **3** - Agregar MyGlobalClass a la matriz de arranque en el archivo de configuración:
>
> ```
> 'bootstrap' => ['log','MyGlobalClass'],
> ```

Es importante tener en cuenta que el componente, debe extender de `CApplicationComponent`

Espero que a ustedes también les ayude.

Comment: Responder con solo enlaces se considera de baja calidad lee [answer]

Comment: @Aprendiz he actualizado la respuesta manteniendo el vínculo a la referencia, gracias!

Comment: Bien hecho  .